# Thread safe Log to text file

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-3, logging, concurrency

While trying to use the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener` 
The object is tyring to access some folder in the ctor (and writing something in it!).

the exception happened in the ctor

some sample code now...

```
FileLogTraceListener logger = new FileLogTraceListener("theName");
Writer.BaseFileName = "Writer";
Writer.CustomLocation = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/logs");
Writer.LogFileCreationSchedule = LogFileCreationScheduleOption.Weekly;
Writer.TraceOutputOptions = TraceOptions.Timestamp;
Writer.AutoFlush = true;
Writer.Delimiter = "|";
Writer.DiskSpaceExhaustedBehavior = DiskSpaceExhaustedOption.DiscardMessages;
Writer.Location = LogFileLocation.Custom;
Writer.Encoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
Writer.IncludeHostName = false;
Writer.MaxFileSize = (1024 * 1024) * 5;            

Writer.WriteLine(message, category);

[UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '\Microsoft Corporation\Internet Information Services\7.0.6000.16386' is denied.]
System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +10797222
System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost) +10589262
System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost) +136
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path) +33
```

help anyone?

Comment: Is this for VB.NET or C#? `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener`

Comment: this is for C# and that is just the name of the DLL that im using

Comment: Try log4net or other logging libraries. It will keep you away from threading issues and other file management activities. You can concentrate on coding, instead of logging.